# How to retrieve content in layout zend framework2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I was using phtml files in zend framework. Now I am using .tpl files.
I found how to use html script and all. But when I want to use php code. Then I'm using:

```
<?php 
    echo "test";
    echo $this->content; 
?>
```

The problem with this is it is in layout.tpl file. Main content is in index.tpl of other module.

Rather than fetching the content of index file It echoing just 'test'.How to make it works?

Edited: I also tried `{$this->content}`.

Comment: Maybe you need use `Smarty` syntax, not `php`.

Comment: if i search am getting suggestion of this syntax only :(

Comment: I got PHP : <?php echo $foo; ?>
Smarty : {$foo} But no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Smarty Templating Engine and the [SmartyModule](https://github.com/MurgaNikolay/SmartyModule), then you will have to use Smarty syntax in your view scripts, since the `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` will be overridden by the Smarty Renderer (and the Smarty Templating Engine).  Also, if you wish to use layouts with Smarty, please see [Smarty's Template Inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/inheritance) mechanism.  Here is an example:

layout.tpl

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{block name=title}Default Page Title{/block}</title>
</head>
<body>
{block name=body}{/block}
</body>
</html>
```

mypage.tpl

```
{extends file="layout.tpl"}
{block name=title}My Page Title{/block}
{block name=body}My HTML Page Body goes here{/block}
```

Otherwise, if you are using the PhpRenderer, it will not "recognize" any templating language, even if you change the view script's file extension to .tpl, since it will simply `include` the content of the view scripts (see lines 502-503 of the renderer's [source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php)).  Therefore, as with any `include`, the PHP code will be executed immediately and stored in the renderer's `$__content` property.  This is probably the reason why your `echo` command is immediately executed.

So, basically, you will have to choose your renderer (PhpRenderer or Smarty Renderer through the SmartyModule) and then abide by its inner workings (PHP/HTML or Smarty syntax (ex. [variables](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl)), respectively).